# Использование полей в протоколах OSPF или BGP для стеганографии

Tags: python, сеть, scapy, ospf

Какое поле в протоколах OSPF или BGP может быть использовано для скрытной передачи информации.
На основе библиотеки scapy (python) возможно изменить любую часть протокола, но какая самая безопасная и незаметная?

Comment: Не совсем понятен практический смысл применения стеганографии в BGP.

Comment: Вариация интервала времени между hello пакетами (четное количество секунд -- 0, нечетное -- 1 ) (понятно, если скорость обмена 0.1 бод вас устраивает) -)